# How to remove the last character from integer value in vb6

Tags: vb6

Hello i am trying to make a code that removes the last digit from an integer example

```
int num = 1234
```

to be

```
int num 123
```

I did the same code in C# but i am failing to do it on vb6 this is the c# code.

```
num = num.Remove(num.length -1)
```

on vb6 i tried something like this

```
num = Len(num) -1
```

but all it does is from

```
num = 1234
```

it makes it

```
num = 1233
```

or just shows

```
num = 3
```

since removed the 4th digit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right path.  The key missing step is to convert the number to a string before manipulating it.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim num As Integer
   Dim s As String
   
   num = 1234
   s = CStr(num)              'convert number to a string
   s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)    'remove last digit
   num = CInt(s)              'convert string back to a number
   
   Debug.Print num
End Sub
```

The error in your code is using `Len` on an Integer.  From the documentation:

> Returns a Long containing the number of characters in a string or the
> number of bytes required to store a variable.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply divide your number by 10:

```
Function TrimInteger(number As Integer) As Integer
    TrimInteger = Int(number / 10)
End Function
```

[Int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions) is used to remove the fractional part of the division result and return the resulting integer value.

You can also declare `number` and the Function's return type as a Long instead of an Integer to support larger numbers:

```
Function TrimNumber(number As Long) As Long
    TrimNumber = Int(number / 10)
End Function
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for a long number - but OP has indicated he's working with integer example. I'd remove that last statement or correct it.